# how to stop auto downloading and saving of pictures and videos on Ionic App

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have a chat application, where there is the possibility to send and receive media (photos and videos), so when I open the message page, it automatically downloads and backs up the media.

I want to stop the download and automatic backup of the media when opening an ionic page, I want it to happen as in WhatsApp, where we download images manually by clicking on it.

Is it possible to do it in ionic? If so, how to do it?

Your help please.
Thank you

Comment: so once somebody sends a link to image - instead of showing that image you could substitute that image src to a placeholder and change it once user clicks. Can you share your code so far?

Comment: Thank you with your help @Sergey, but I did not understand how to do it, here is my code below

Answer (score 0):

**Get messages on the server, then view them**

```
this.chatService.getHistoriqueMsg(msgListData).then((result) => {
            let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
            if (data.status == "success") {
                if (data.result.messages.length > 0) {
                    data.result.messages.forEach(element => {

                        if (element.typemessage == "IMAGE") {
                            let image = JSON.parse(element.message);
                            let url = encodeURI(this.constant.urlmsgImage + image.filepath);
                            //Save image to galery
                            let album = 'EBMChat';
                            this.photoLibrary.requestAuthorization().then((auto) => {
                                this.photoLibrary.saveImage(url, album).then((imgSave) => {

                                    const message: ChatMessage = {
                                        id: element.id,
                                        from: element.from,
                                        ufrom_username: element.ufrom_username,
                                        ufrom_avatar: (element.ufrom_avatar == null || element.ufrom_avatar == undefined) ? "./assets/imgs/default-profile-pic.png" : this.constant.urlServerAvatar + element.ufrom_avatar,
                                        to: element.to,
                                        uto_username: element.uto_username,
                                        uto_avatar: (element.uto_avatar == null || element.uto_avatar == undefined) ? "./assets/imgs/default-profile-pic.png" : this.constant.urlServerAvatar + element.uto_avatar,
                                        message: this.constant.urlmsgImage + image.filepath,
                                        sent: element.sent,
                                        read: element.read,
                                        direction: element.direction,
                                        typemessage: element.typemessage,
                                        deleteto: element.deleteto,
                                        deletefrom: element.deletefrom,
                                        ownership: element.from == this.user.userid ? 'mine' : 'other',
                                        imgSend: (element.read == "1") ? "./assets/ebm/ic_msg_lu.png" : "./assets/ebm/ic_sent_state.png"
                                    };

                                    this.msgList.push(message);
                                }).catch(err => {console.log(err)})
                            }).catch(err => {console.log(err)})

                        } else {
                            let emoji = require('node-emoji');
                            const message: ChatMessage = {
                                id: element.id,
                                from: element.from,
                                ufrom_username: element.ufrom_username,
                                ufrom_avatar: (element.ufrom_avatar == null || element.ufrom_avatar == undefined) ? "./assets/imgs/default-profile-pic.png" : this.constant.urlServerAvatar + element.ufrom_avatar,
                                to: element.to,
                                uto_username: element.uto_username,
                                uto_avatar: (element.uto_avatar == null || element.uto_avatar == undefined) ? "./assets/imgs/default-profile-pic.png" : this.constant.urlServerAvatar + element.uto_avatar,
                                message: emoji.emojify(element.message),
                                sent: element.sent,
                                read: element.read,
                                direction: element.direction,
                                typemessage: element.typemessage,
                                deleteto: element.deleteto,
                                deletefrom: element.deletefrom,
                                ownership: element.from == this.user.userid ? 'mine' : 'other',
                                imgSend: (element.read == "1") ? "./assets/ebm/ic_msg_lu.png" : "./assets/ebm/ic_sent_state.png"
                            };

                            this.msgList.push(message);
                        }
                    });

                    const currentGroupedMessages = _.groupBy(this.msgList, (message) => {
                        return this.timeStamp(message.sent);
                    });
                    // Transform dictionary into an array since Angular's view engine doesn't know how
                    // to iterate through it
                    this.groupedMessages = Object.keys(currentGroupedMessages).map((timestamp: string) => {
                        return {
                            timestamp: timestamp,
                            messages: currentGroupedMessages[timestamp],
                            today: this.timeStamp(Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000)) === timestamp
                        };
                    });

                }
            } 
        })
```